# Error Sending ONLY Image/Video file

Tags: java, android, io, client-server, file-transfer

I'm trying to share files between my pc & android device over wifi. Strange thing is text and audio files are being perfectly transferred, while the images and video files fail to render. 
Here's the main piece of code:

**Sender:**

```
BufferedOutputStream writer = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
while ((read = stream.read(buffer)) != -1)
    writer.write(buffer, 0, read);
```

**Receiver:**

```
BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
while (!store.complete) {
    read = input.read(buffer, 0 , MAX_SIZE_OF_BUFFER);
    String data = new String(buffer);
    // Need to do some data manipulation (like removing a string which i appended
    // while sending )
    outputStream.write(data.getBytes());
}
```

**Note: Even the size of the image/video file at the receiver is equal to the file being sent, still it fails to render.**

Thanks in Advance!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assume that converting a byte[] to String and then converting it back to byte[] will give you the original byte[].

For example, the following does *not* output the original byte array:

```
    byte[] buffer = {-127};
    for (byte b : new String(buffer).getBytes()) { System.out.print(" " + b); }
```

To solve your problem, do your data manipulation (appending and removing your data) as bytes and don't convert to and from String.

Comment: Thanks!!:) It would be of great help if you can explain me is this happening.

Comment: I can't find a concise explanation, but fundamentally it's because Java uses UTF-16, which is a variable-length encoding.  Perhaps the byte sequence in my example is not valid UTF-16, and therefor the underlying bytes are modified during conversion from byte[] to String.